# Using jQuery DataTables with Select extension and checkboxes

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've successfully integrated the [DataTables Checkbox](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html) option into my page, but I can't find anything on how to actually UTILIZE these once they're in.  Since they don't use `<input>` to create these and rely on CSS `:before` and `:after`, I'm not sure how I get the checkboxes to do something when I click them.

Is there any documentation on this that I just can't find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use API methods such as [`rows({ selected: true })`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows()) or [`cells({ selected: true })`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cells()) to get selected entities.

See our article [jQuery DataTables – Row selection using checkboxes and Select extension](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-row-selection-using-checkboxes-and-select-extension/) or [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/snqw56dw/) for advanced example on how to use checkboxes for row selection with jQuery DataTables and Select extension.

Comment: wow - January 16th?  I just made the mark :)  The additional code you show on here for the Submit button was absolutely wonderful, and the entire tutorial is laid out really well.  Thanks so much!

Comment: This works really well - the only thing I can't figure out is how you enabled the submit button.  In your JQuery code, you have this `$('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e){`, but I don't see anywhere where you're adding this button to the code, either through DataTables itself, or through the `HTML` section of your code.

Comment: @BrianPowell, Submit button is part of HTML code, see [corresponding jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/snqw56dw/).

Comment: @Gyrocode.com sorry for "hijacking" the question, but if you could take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72722463/datatables-checkboxes-extension-combined-with-sortable I'd be really grateful!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found where this is on the Datatables site:

https://datatables.net/extensions/select/

and

https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/get.html